# what is a file handle and where it is useful for a programmer?

Tags: file, assembly, handle

I am learning assembly language along with C. this new chapter I started talks about 'file handles', file handles for screen display and file handles for keyboard input etc. I don't know what is a file handle? I am referring to IBM PC ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE PROGRAMMING by Peter Abel

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_%28computing%29

Comment: The Unix equivalent is a "file descriptor".  It's exactly the same concept (an integer that you can pass to the kernel, where it knows about the already-open file).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a generic concept generally called a "handle" in the context of computer software APIs.  In the comments you have probably found a link to the [Wikipedia article on that subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_%28computing%29).

You are dealing with a specific implementation of a handle data type -- the IBM PC/DOS file handles returned from the `int 0x21` interface.  If you would like to learn more about these specific file handles, you might want to consult the book [Undocumented DOS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163287X), which details the in-memory data structures which allow you to investigate these handles further.

Another specific type of handle is the *file descriptor* returned from the POSIX-standard interface named `open()`.  This function is implemented in the C run-time library on platforms such as Linux,  Windows NT, Mac OS, and many other systems.  The integer returned from a call to `open()` may not be a negative number.

Unless you are running under DOS, your file handles are probably provided by the Windows NT Operating System.  These file handles are returned from `CreateFile()` (which is used to open as well as create files), and the only illegal value for a handle returned from this function is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.  I.e., the Windows NT API may return what would be considered (via casting) a "negative" integer, although it has opened the file.

In all of these cases, the file handle is used to refer to some data structure that keeps track of how the file is open.  One important thing which is tracked is the current file *position*.  The position or *pointer* is set in POSIX by the `lseek()` function and is read by the `tell()` function.  Any `read()` or `write()` takes place from the position of the current file pointer.

Your program can open the same file under two different handles.  In this case, the file pointer for each handle is distinct.  Updating the file pointer of one handle using `lseek()` will not affect the file pointer of the other handle to the same file.

[image: Undocumented DOS]

Answer (score 11):

A file handle is an integer value which is used to address an open file. Such handles are highly operating system specific, but on systems that support the open() call, you create a handle like this:

```
int handle = open( "foo.txt", OTHER_STUFF_HERE );
```

You can then use the handle with read/write calls. The non-portability of handles mean that most people avoid them and instead use the stream library functions in C, such as  fopen, fread, fwrite etc.

Comment: Most people use fopen()?  That simply is not true.

Comment: @Heath What, you think most people use open()? Not in my experience.

Comment: Wait, whait, there's people that actually use open()???  :-)  Yeah, OK, I'm one of them, but only for OS dependent stuff that you just can't do with fopen()d files...

Comment: @Brian I'm sure people do use open, I'm sure  Linus uses it all the time :-) I'm equally sure most people don't.

Comment: @Neil -- It's not the "system" which supports open(), it is the runtime library.  ```open()``` works just as well under Windows NT (without cygwin) as it does under Linux.

Answer (score 4):

A handle is something the kernel uses internally to access some resource. Only the kernel really knows what it means, the user process is only told what value to use when it wants to access this resource. They have another advantage in that file handles can be shared among processes - whereas you can't do this with pointers.

Windows uses handles all over the place... files, bitmaps, device contexts, fonts, etc.